# If location.search == '?test=yes' any anything after does something else

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the query string in my javascript in my website, is there like a wildcard tag in javascript so it could be like
* = wildcard

```
var x = location.search;
if (x=='?test=yes') {
  window.location.replace('http://google.com')
}
else {
  if (x=='?test=yes&*=123') {
    window.location.replace('http://youtube.com')
  }
}
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: Try [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of achieving this would be with **[`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)**, wherein you can simply check that `x` contains the starting string `?test=yes`:

```js
const x = '?test=yes&*=123';

if (x.includes('?test=yes')) {
  console.log('yes');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `includes`:

```js
const x = "https://example.com?test=yes&*=123";
console.log(x.includes("?test=yes"));
```

You could alternatively use a regular expression:

```js
const x = "https://example.com?test=yes&*=123";
console.log(/]?test=yes/.test(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in class to handle this now.

```
var params = new URL(location.href).searchParams;
```

This will return a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object that you can use to check the query string.

```
if(params.has('test')){
    console.log(params.get('test'));
}
```